# Unable to consume APIs of Admin SDK (JAVA)

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have created a business account for testing purpose.
I would like to consume admin SDK APIs (to fetch users, groups, user profile images and all)

I could not find any best way to start with.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most straight forward way to start with a brand new API project is here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites

1) Enable API access in your Admin Console
2) Enable ADmin SDK in your API Console
3) Create OAuth 2.0 Client ID in your API Console 
4) Pick and install the client library you wanna write your app in (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/setup).

I think that should get you started at least.